# Why does Postgres still do a Bitmap Heap Scan when a covering index is used?

Tags: postgresql

The table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "audit_log" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('audit_log_id_seq'::regclass),
  "entity" varchar(50) COLLATE "public"."ci",
  "updated" timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
  "transaction_id" uuid,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_audit_log" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

It contains millions of row.

I tried adding an index on one column like this:

```
CREATE INDEX "testing" ON "audit_log" USING btree (
  "entity" COLLATE "public"."ci" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);
```

Then ran the following query over both the indexed column, and the primary key:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT entity, id FROM audit_log WHERE entity = 'abcd'
```

As I expected, the query plan uses both a Bitmap Index Scan (to find the 'entity' column, presumably) and a Bitmap Heap Scan (to retrieve the 'id' column, I assume):

```
Gather  (cost=2640.10..260915.23 rows=87166 width=122) (actual time=2.828..3.764 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on audit_log  (cost=1640.10..251198.63 rows=36319 width=122) (actual time=0.061..0.062 rows=0 loops=3)
        Recheck Cond: ((entity)::text = '1234'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on testing  (cost=0.00..1618.31 rows=87166 width=0) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((entity)::text = '1234'::text)
```

Next I added an INCLUDE column to the index in order to make it cover the above query:

```
DROP INDEX testing

CREATE INDEX testing ON audit_log USING btree (
    "entity" COLLATE "public"."ci" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
)
INCLUDE
(
  "id"
)
```

Then I reran my query, but it still does the Bitmap Heap Scan:

```
Gather  (cost=2964.10..261239.23 rows=87166 width=122) (actual time=2.711..3.570 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on audit_log  (cost=1964.10..251522.63 rows=36319 width=122) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=0 loops=3)
        Recheck Cond: ((entity)::text = '1234'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on testing  (cost=0.00..1942.31 rows=87166 width=0) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((entity)::text = '1234'::text)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PostgreSQL implements row versioning using a concept called *visibility*. Each query knows which version of a row it can see.

Now that visibility information is stored in the table row, but not in the index entry, so that table has to be visited just to test if the row is visible or not.

Because of that, every bitmap index scan needs a bitmap heap scan.

To overcome the unfortunate property, PostgreSQL has introduced the *visibility map*, a data structure that stores for each 8kB-block of the table if all rows in that block are visible to everybody. If that is the case, looking up the table row can be skipped. This is only possible for a regular index scan, not a bitmap index scan.

That visibility map is maintained by `VACUUM`. So run `VACUUM` on the table, then you may get an *index only scan* on the table.

If that alone is not enough, you could try `CLUSTER` to rewrite the table in index order.

---

Some detail information on how PostgreSQL estimates the cost of an index scan. The following code is from `cost_index` in `src/backend/optimizer/path/costsize.c`:

```c
    /*----------
[...]
     * If it's an index-only scan, then we will not need to fetch any heap
     * pages for which the visibility map shows all tuples are visible.
     * Hence, reduce the estimated number of heap fetches accordingly.
     * We use the measured fraction of the entire heap that is all-visible,
     * which might not be particularly relevant to the subset of the heap
     * that this query will fetch; but it's not clear how to do better.
     *----------
     */

[...]

        if (indexonly)
            pages_fetched = ceil(pages_fetched * (1.0 - baserel->allvisfrac));
```

`allvisfrac` is calculated using `pg_class.relallvisible`, which holds an estimate for the number of all-visible pages in the table, and `pg_class.relpages`.

Comment: Hey Laurenz, great answer, pointed me into a lot of useful documentation.
Could you elaborate a bit on when exactly psql decides to do a bitmap scan anyways when a vm exists? Is it when the vm has sufficient pages marked as changed, or does it already start with just a single changed page? If there is a threshhold, is there a good rule-of-thumb? Does the plan change on-the-fly to a bitmap scan when an covering index scan notices that a majority pages it has to visit end up touching the pages anyways? (Since that information might not be available at plan time)

Comment: @Joe I have extended the answer to cover that. There is no good rule of thumb. PostgreSQL will estimate the cost of an index scan, the cost of an index-only scan and the cost of a bitmap index scan and will use whatever ends up having the lowest cost.

Comment: Great! That snippet answers practically all my questions.